# ggplot2: Annotate stacked bars with totals for each bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to annotate a plot so as to show the totals for each column. For example

```
 ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + 
        geom_bar(position="fill") +
        scale_y_continuous(name="proportion")
```

This will produce a stacked barplot. However it is difficult to know what is n for each of the bars. I1,SI2 and so on. How can I annotate it so that, for each bar, n is displayed at the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to compute the totals before plotting, then adding them to the plot separately. First, we calculate columns totals:

```
totals = tapply(diamonds$price, diamonds$clarity, length)
dd = data.frame(clarity = names(totals), labels = as.vector(totals), y= 1)
```

Then we use `geom_text` to add the totals:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity)) + 
    geom_bar(aes( fill=cut), position="fill") +
    scale_y_continuous(name="proportion") + 
    geom_text(data=dd, aes(x=clarity, y=y, label=labels), size=4)
```

Comment: Why did you specify the fill parameter within the geom_bar() aesthetic?

Comment: If you specify `fill` in `ggplot` it's inherited by `geom_text` - this causes problems.

Comment: Search for order and ggplot2 on SO.