# Adding totals above a proportions stacked bar chart with multiple response variables

Tags: r, stacked-bar-chart

I am trying to add totals to a stacked bar chart where I depict proportions and where both the x and y variables are multiple response ones. I managed to do it with total counts despite getting a warning message, but it totally gets messed up when I try to add totals to the proportions bar chart.

This is an excerpt of my df hnvf3:

```
structure(list(HNV_grasslands = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), HNV_arable = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), HNV_permanent_crop = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), HNV_mosaic = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L), Animal_vegetal = c("", "Both", "Both", "Both", "", 
"Vegetal species", "Vegetal species", "", "Both", "Animal species", 
"Both")), row.names = 10:20, class = "data.frame")
```

This is the code I used for adding the total in the counts version and despite getting a warning:

> The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: fill This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in the data. Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical variable into a factor?

I get the total counts on top.

```
hnvf4 <- hnvf3 %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("HNV"),
    names_to = c("HNV"),
    names_prefix = "HNV_",
    values_to = "value1") |>
    filter(value1 == 1 & Animal_vegetal !="") |>
  select(-value1) # pone esto para que hnvf2 no sea todo "1" en todas las filas, sino el valor de provisioning, etc
glimpse(hnvf4)

hnvf4 |>
  ggplot(aes(x = HNV,fill = factor(Animal_vegetal, levels=c("Animal species", "Vegetal species", "Both")))) +
  geom_bar()+
  geom_text(stat ="count",aes(label=after_stat(count), group= HNV, vjust= -1))+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FDCDAC", "#B3E2CD","#CBD5E8"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.line.y = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, colour = "black"),
        axis.ticks.length.y.left = unit(.25, "cm"))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill=NA))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c('arable land', 'grasslands', 'mosaic landscape', 
                            'permanent croplands')) +
  labs(x= "HNV farmland type", y="Number of studies", fill= "")+
  #geom_text(data=stacked, aes(label=nsum, variable),size=2, vjust= 1)+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin=margin(r= 15)))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits= c(0,100), breaks=c(0,25,50,75, 100),expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(legend.position = c(.99, .95),
        legend.justification = c("right", "top"))
```

And this is the coding that is not working for the proportions:

```
hnvf4%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = HNV,fill = factor(Animal_vegetal,levels=c("Animal species", "Vegetal species", "Both")))) +
  geom_bar(position="fill")+
  #geom_text(stat ="count",aes(label=after_stat(count), group= HNV, vjust= -1))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FDCDAC", "#B3E2CD","#CBD5E8"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.line.y = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, colour = "black"),
        axis.ticks.length.y.left = unit(.25, "cm"))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill=NA))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c('arable land', 'grasslands', 'mosaic landscape', 
                            'permanent croplands')) +
  labs(x= "HNV farmland type", y="Proportion of studies", fill= "")+
  #geom_text(data=stacked, aes(label=nsum, variable),size=2, vjust= 1)+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin=margin(r= 15)))+
  # para que no haya espacio extra y que el eje y salga de 0
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

I have also checked the following entries in stackflow: [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72266695/add-totals-on-top-of-each-bar), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450700/ggplot2-annotate-stacked-bars-with-totals-for-each-bar?rq=3), [question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811999/ggplot-add-aggregated-summaries-to-a-bar-plot?rq=3), [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656846/draw-the-sum-value-above-the-stacked-bar-in-ggplot2), but I find it difficult to create a new data frame for the `geom_text()` since I do not have a variable that displays counts of my variables. I have tried to modify my data and create a new df with counts for each variable, but still it does not work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you tried regarding creating a numeric version of your data is the easiest when comes to plotting. I've provided a `tidyverse` method to sum your groups.

The thing you needed to do for the text labels on your proportions plot was to set `position = "fill"`. I have swapped `geom_text()` for `stat_summary()` and added `position = "fill"` to the proportions plot so the labels and bars display correctly.

Note that I could not find a way to plot text outside the y-axis using `geom_text()` or `stat_summary()` if `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))`. So I resorted to `coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')` to place your labels above the bar. If you want to use `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))`, place the labels inside the plot by changing `vjust`. There may be a way to plot above the bar using `annotate()` or similar, comment below if someone knows how.

**Data and Packages**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Sum species groups by HNV values and add factor levels for Animal_vegetal
hnvf4 <- hnvf3 %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("HNV"),
    names_to = c("HNV"),
    names_prefix = "HNV_",
    values_to = "value1") |>
  filter(value1 == 1 & Animal_vegetal != "") |>
  select(-value1) |> 
  group_by(HNV, Animal_vegetal) |>
  summarise(count = n(), .groups = "drop") |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(Animal_vegetal = factor(Animal_vegetal, 
                                  levels = c("Animal species", 
                                             "Vegetal species", 
                                             "Both")))
```

**Counts Plot**

```
ggplot(data = hnvf4) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = HNV, y = count, fill = Animal_vegetal),
           stat = "identity") +
  stat_summary(aes(x = HNV, y = count, label = after_stat(y)),
               fun.y = "sum",
               geom = "text", 
               colour = "black",
               vjust = -1) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("arable land", "grasslands", "mosaic landscape", 
                            "permanent croplands")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100), 
                     breaks = c(0,25,50,75, 100),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FDCDAC", "#B3E2CD","#CBD5E8")) +
  labs(x = "HNV farmland type", y="Number of studies", fill = "") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, colour = "black"),
        axis.ticks.length.y.left = unit(.25, "cm"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r= 15)),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        legend.position = c(.99, .95),
        legend.justification = c("right", "top"))
```

[image: result1]

**Proportions Plot**

```
ggplot(data = hnvf4) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = HNV, y = count, fill = Animal_vegetal),
           stat = "identity",
           position = "fill") +
  stat_summary(aes(x = HNV, y = count, label = after_stat(y)),
               fun.y = "sum",
               geom = "text",
               position = "fill",
               colour = "black",
               vjust = -1) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels =c("arable land", "grasslands", "mosaic landscape", 
                             "permanent croplands")) +
  # scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FDCDAC", "#B3E2CD","#CBD5E8") )+
  labs(x = "HNV farmland type", y="Proportion of studies", fill = "") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, colour = "black"),
        axis.ticks.length.y.left = unit(.25, "cm"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 15)))
```

[image: result2]